# Multiple ng-repeats-start attributes through multiple levels

Tags: angularjs, nested-loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to loop through four levels with `ng-repeat`, but `ng-repeat` fails after the third level.

How can I use `ng-repeat` for multiple repeats?

```
<tbody ng-repeat="company in companies">
     <tr>
         <td>{{company.name}}</td>
     </tr>           
     <tr ng-repeat-start="child in company.Children">
         <td>{{child.name}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat-start="child2 in child.Children">
        <td>{{child2.name}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="child3 in child2.Children">
        <td>{{child3.name}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried to end both loops like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

However, Angular doesn't check that two loops have to be closed. You can only close one loop and that's my problem.

Comment: Could you not just flatten your data arrays in controller? Also why doesn't simple `ng-repeat` work?

Comment: because i am using a jquery library for buliding a tree grid. so i need to loop through the data in this way to get the right tree structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works totally fine for me, as you can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jrFA11G0ZK7JWzJ86OD?p=preview). But errors occured when I tried to use an old angular versions (before v1.2). I did not need to change your code to

```
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```